Graceful finishing another thread from std::terminate
I'm considering implementation of async logging. That means that several worker threads produce messages in memory and put them into a lock-free queue, and a single logging thread consumes this queue and performs blocking IO operations in background. The downside of this approach is that if any worker thread throws uncaught exception, the std::terminate is called, and the logging thread may not finish its output. This is very undesirable, so I need to ensure that prior to program termination the queue would be emptied and all IO operations would be finished. For simplicity I'm considering the case when the logger itself may not cause the termination, and that termination is not caused by exception from static or thread local objects, that it is not caused by destruction of a joinable thread, etc.
What happens with other threads if one thread throws an uncaught exception? Can I yield to other threads from std::terminate, block on mutex or implement busy waiting? I need to prevent adding new messages to logging queue letting the logger to empty it, and then I need to wait for the IO completion: should I busy wait on an atomic?

If the only problem is uncaught exceptions, why not catch the exceptions and end the threads so that the program can shutdown gracefully?

@TedLyngmo, the main problem is legacy code where everything horrible is possible. So I'm considering the case when worker threads are being developed by the worst engineers ever, and I'm controlling only the logger and std::terminate.

If logging is critical consider sending it to an out-of-process logger (log server). That way it can log the whole remainder of the queue even if your process is crashing.

@PepijnKramer, that is my plan, but the main question is how much freedom I have in my process. Sending something to an out-of-process logger is most likely a blocking IO operation, so I wish to make it asynchronous.

You can override the terminate handler and tell the logger to stop taking extra inputs and finish its ongoing work then terminate, the main problem is that once terminate is called you can assume the heap is corrupted and not accessible and many similar restrictions, ie: how much longer should the application continue working once it is in a corrupted state.

@AhmedAEK I understand that there is no bulletproof ideal way to handle all possible cases, but I need a practical solution: to log the events that happened before the crash, and if something more severe happens (like heap corruption), I would just try to do my best with the fingers crossed.

You could send the log entries to another process as Pepijn suggested and it wouldn't have to be very time consuming. I'm guessing you want to catch the issues in order to be able to fix them? If so, using sanitizers may be a good idea. I find using ASan and UBsan in combination and TSan separately to be good ways to catch issues.

@TedLyngmo, catching the issues is not the goal. Consider the team who refuses using good practices. The worker threads are being developed by crazy people who want to make you harm, you control only the logger thread, logging API, and the terminate handler, and you need to log the messages from all those insane threads prior to letting them collapse.

Sounds like an awful environment :-) Well, then, don't even bother with a logging thread and distance your code from theirs. Just provide an API which sends the logs to a logging daemon. If you are on a unix-like platform, you could just send stuff to syslog. man 3 syslog should be a good entrypoint.

@TedLyngmo I want to get prepared to send to something more advanced: to an external server with a NoSQL-based logging database, etc. The daemon is ok, but I wish to know the limitations inside a single process.

There are a lot of ready logging frameworks, like DLT which is mainly used in the automotive industry. You could make your own daemon that runs on the local host and provide an API for it that the crazy code can use. I would try to make the API as resilient to the crazy code as possible. No threads. Just forward messages to your own logging daemon. It can then forward the messages to another server if needed, but to start with, it could just write to a local file.

Also, you could setup centralized logging with syslog-ng for example. It has a built-in journaling system which is much like a database that you can query etc.

@TedLyngmo, I'm working in a large organization that is crazy about security. So the choice of tools is not under my control. From that perspective I'm exploring the playground and consider different approaches that I would use later negotiating the solution.

If they are crazy about security, one thing to bring up is the quality of the code that you have to deal with. Anyway, if what you have now is good enough for the org. then using syslog or your own daemon shouldn't be a problem. If they want something that's been proven to work, using a framework like DTL could be an option. It runs in cars all over the world.

Under crashing conditions there will never be a guarantee everything can still be logged.  IMO logging to another process using a loopback interface first should be very very fast (loopback should use some kind of shared memory) and only the log information should be queued there (do not send fully formatted messages). That other process can then forward to whatever log solution is available/allowed in your organization.

Side note : I usually also completely abstract away from logging so I can change to whatever log system later (zero assumptions about logging infrastructure in business logic). E.g. like this https://onlinegdb.com/uyuxg5_ODw.  Also very helpful for unit testing where you don't want to depend on logging infrastructure either.

@DmitryKuzminov "worker threads are being developed by the worst engineers ever". Don't let them directly create threads. Force then to use your thread creation API, then wrap ever thread function call within proper try-catch block before passing it to std::jthread. Take responsibility for thread management and disallowed arbitrary thread creation.

If they are so "crazy about security", then there's plenty of evidence of malware exploiting uncaptured UB in code(search why C gets is deprecated). Convince them that multi-threading has too many pitfalls, and needs further insight. Organisational problems cannot be solved by programming tricks.
